# angular js 1.6.4 $http.post example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js 1.6.4 I call my asmx service by angular $http.post but I got internal server error, my service not called, I could not debug much.

```
(function () {
        angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("TestController", function ($scope,$http) {
                 $scope.SaveFormData = function () {
                    $scope.msg;
                    var user = {};
                    user.FirstName = $scope.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = $scope.LastName;   


                    $http.post('http://localhost:50829/pages1/TestService.asmx/SavePersonalData', JSON.stringify({ data: user })).then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data) {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            $scope.msg = response.data.d;
                        }

                    }, function (response) {
                        Console.log("Service not Exists");
                        Console.log(response.status);
                        console.log(response.statusText);

                    });

                }             

                }
            });
    })();
```

and here is my asmx service

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string SavePersonalData(PersonalData data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.FirstName);
        return "saved";
    }
```

how do I post my html form FirstName to my asmx service.

Comment: For angular 1.x questions please tag [tag:angularjs], the [tag:angular] tag is for version 2 and later.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify($scope.FirstName),` — if your data is so very explicitly JSON … why are you claiming it is form encoded?: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: You should not use `JSON.stringify` on a single string variable, that makes no sense. That method exists to transform an *object* to a json formatted string.

Comment: thanks for your response , I modified as per your guidence but my service not called.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an object with LoC

```
data: { FirstName: $scope.FirstName },
```

So you need to receive an object in c#. Modify your c# code to accept an object that matches what you are sending.

Add a class

```
public class PersonalData {
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

And your web method

```
[WebMethod]
public string SavePersonalData(PersonalData data)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.FirstName);
    return "saved";
}
```

Comment: hi lgor, thanks for your help, its working now, and I learned how to use angular $http.post method and take the response